Seeking advice on this method of calculating the square of an integer
#Hi all. I would like to ask for advice on this method of calculation
Example 1. 19 multiply by 19

Multiply 9 by 9 to get 81, then carry over (8) so we have 1
Bring 19 plus 9 to get 28, then bring multiply 28 by 1 = 28
Bring 28 plus 8(from the carry over) to get 36
Arrange the numbers in order to get 361

#Example 2. 58 multiply by 58

Multiply 8 by 8 to get 64, then carry over (6) so we have 4
Bring 58 plus 8 to get 66, then bring multiply 66 by 5 = 330
Bring 330 plus 6(from the carry over) to get 336.
Arrange the numbers in order to get 3364

#Example 3. 247 multiply by 247

Multiply 7 by 7 to get 49, then carry over (4) so we have 9 in unit digit.
Bring 47 plus 7 to get 54, then bring multiply 54 by 4 = 216
Bring 216 plus 4(from the carry over) to get 220, then carry over (22) so we have 0 in Ten's digit.
Bring 247 plus 47 to get 294, then bring multiply 294 by 2 = 588
Bring 588 plus 22(from the carry over) to get 610.
Arrange the numbers in order to get 61009.

From the example I've provided, I hope everyone can understand it somewhat. This method is one that I came up with myself, and I am not sure if anyone else has thought of it. Therefore, I would appreciate any feedback on this method.
Thank you

For two digit integers $10a+b$, with $0\le a,b\le 9$, your formula can be recovered in the following way$$(10a+b)^2=100a^2+20ab+b^2=(10a+2b)10a+b^2=(10a+b+b)10a+b^2$$
The formula for integers with three digits can be found in the same way. An easier way to write that would be $$(100a+10b+c)^2=(100a)^2+(10b)^2+c^2+2(100a)(10b)+2(100a)c+2(10b)c$$
